# Fix position of div tag inside dialog op-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have dialog box which comes on clicking a button. In the dialog box i have a button and other content. I want to make that button position fixed inside dialog pop-up.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('#footer_buttons').addClass('sticky');

}
else {
    $('##footer_buttons').removeClass('sticky');
}
});

<style>
  .sticky{ 
    position : fixed;
 }
</style>
```

I used above code to make the button position fix, it worked outside the dialog box but  not working when the same code is used inside the dialog box. I can make a button fix by adding a min-height to dialog and make the dialog content scrollable. But I don't want to add any scroll to the content inside dialog box. 
     Can any one help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) property:

> **fixed**:
>       Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it
>   when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on
>   every page.

So it doesn't matter where your element is. If you apply the `fixed` position, the `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` values are relative to the screen's viewport (visible area in browser).

In your case you should use `absolute` positioning and set the position using two of the four positioning properties: top, right, bottom, left. Don't forget to add `position: relative or absolute` to the modal container.

Comment: when i add position to modal it is giving error:   Uncaught ReferenceError: absolute is not defined.  I added position to model as  $("#dialog").modal({position: absolute });

Comment: absolute must be a string not a variable: $("#dialog").modal({position: 'absolute'});

Comment: Also you can't set the position using .modal(..). You should set it using css: $('#dialog').css({position: 'absolute'});